# Tracking down high CPU core utilisation

Tags: linux, debian, process, multi-core

I have a system with 24 cores and for some reason only the first core is at 100% utilisation while the others are in the range of 20-25%.

I would like to get all processes that are running on the first core. The OS is Debian 6.0.

Comment: Why do you care? (Are you actually experiencing a performance problem?) -- Idle CPU is *wasted* CPU: An ideal system will always have 100% CPU utilization, with every core actively servicing a process (or the system's own needs)...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the great command **top**. If a process only use one core it is because this process dont support multicore.